# Como salvar objetos Javascript no formato JSON na localStorage, e depois desserializá-los?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

estou obtendo valores de um form no html, depois eu quero usar uma função para pegar esses valores e criar um objeto, fazendo deles atributos deste objeto.

Depois, eu desejo guardar esse objeto no localStorage do navegador, no formato Json, de forma que eu possa buscá-lo de volta depois...

Segue o que eu fiz até agora:

```
<div id="formulario" style="display:none">
   <form onsubmit="return guardaFormulario();">
      <div>
         <label for="nome"> Nome: </label>
         <input type="text" id="nome" />
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="agencia"> Agência: </label>
         <input type="text" id="agencia" />
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="conta"> Conta: </label>
         <input type="text" id="conta" />
      </div>
      <div class="button">
         <button type="submit">Localizar conta de cliente</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<script>
   function guardaFormulario(){
    var contaCliente = new Object();
    contaCliente.nome = getElementById('nome');
    contaCliente.agencia = getElementById('agencia');
    contaCliente.conta = getElementById('conta');

    //Aqui eu salvo o objeto no localStorage, como um objeto Json
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Ao fazer `contaCliente.nome = getElementById('nome')` você pega o html do input, não o seu valor. É isso mesmo que quer?

Comment: Na verdade, eu quero o valor digitado pelo usuário na input nome. Nesse caso, como eu faria?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível salvar formulários <form> no localStorage com Javascript puro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293235/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-salvar-formul%c3%a1rios-form-no-localstorage-com-javascript-puro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nada como um teste para saber o que está acontecendo (com algumas correções):

- `getElementById()` não funcionará se não usar `document` antes
- Retirar o `display: none` para poder enxergar o formulário
- Em vez de colocar um `onsubmit=""` no formulário, coloque um `onclick=""` no botão e o defina do tipo `button` para não recarregar a página

Código:

```
function guardaFormulario() {
    //Primeiro como você está fazendo (com as correções):
    var contaCliente = new Object();
    contaCliente.nome = document.getElementById('nome');
    contaCliente.agencia = document.getElementById('agencia');
    contaCliente.conta = document.getElementById('conta');

    console.log(contaCliente.valueOf());

    //Agora como eu acredito que você queira fazer:
    var contaCliente = new Object();
    contaCliente.nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    contaCliente.agencia = document.getElementById('agencia').value;
    contaCliente.conta = document.getElementById('conta').value;

    console.log(contaCliente.valueOf());
  }

<div id="formulario">

  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="nome"> Nome: </label>
      <input type="text" id="nome" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="agencia"> Agência: </label>
      <input type="text" id="agencia" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="conta"> Conta: </label>
      <input type="text" id="conta" />
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button onclick="guardaFormulario();" type="button">Localizar conta de cliente</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Na primeira saída do console aparecerá um objeto com elementos html, e na segunda um objeto com os valores dos inputs do formulário

Mas ainda sim esse código pode ser simplificado (como eu faria e com o localStorage):

```
<div id="formulario">

  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="nome"> Nome: </label>
      <input type="text" id="nome" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="agencia"> Agência: </label>
      <input type="text" id="agencia" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="conta"> Conta: </label>
      <input type="text" id="conta" />
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button id="enviar" type="button">Localizar conta de cliente</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  //Variáveis dos inputs (html, sem o .value)
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
  var agencia = document.getElementById('agencia');
  var conta = document.getElementById('conta');
  //Variável do objeto que será guardado
  var obj;

  //Adiciona um ouvinte de evento ao botão para quando o usuário clicar nele
  document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Monta o objeto que será salvo
    obj = {
      nome: nome.value,
      agencia: agencia.value,
      conta: conta.value
    };

    //Mostra no console o objeto antes de ser salvo no localStorage
    console.log(obj.valueOf());

    //Salva o objeto no localStorage
    localStorage[nome.value] = JSON.stringify(obj);

    //Mostra no console o objeto salvo
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage[nome.value]).valueOf());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Eu não mudaria o evento do `form.submit` para o `button.click`, pois há outras maneiras de se enviar um form sem usar um botão de submit. Um deles e dar um enter no último `input[text]` do form. Por esse motivo eu sempre uso o evento `form.submit` e uso `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: PS: não está errada a resposta, quis apenas adicionar informações que podem ajudar na tomada de decisão de alguém que ler os comentários. :D

Comment: @fernandosavio eu também :), mas para não complicar deixei desse modo

Answer (score 3):

errado

```
getElementById('nome')
```

correto

```
document.getElementById('nome').value
```

**Script**

```
function guardaFormulario(){

    nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    agencia = document.getElementById('agencia').value;
    conta = document.getElementById('conta').value;

    var testObject = { 'nome': nome, 'agencia': agencia, 'conta': conta };

     // Coloca o objeto no  storage
    localStorage.setItem('dadosBancarios', JSON.stringify(testObject));

    // Recupera o objeto do storage
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('dadosBancarios');

    console.log(retrievedObject);                  

}
```

> para ver o formulário tem que retirar `display: none`

**HTML**

```
<div id="formulario">

        <form onsubmit="return guardaFormulario();">
            <div>
                <label for="nome"> Nome: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nome" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="agencia"> Agência: </label>
                <input type="text" id="agencia" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="conta"> Conta: </label>
                <input type="text" id="conta" />
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <button type="submit">Localizar conta de cliente</button>
            </div>

        </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Vou testar sua opção aqui Léo. Valeu

Comment: Cara, eu fiz dessa forma, mas o conteúdo das variáveis não é salvo. O resultado que aparece é esse:   {nome: {0: {}, 1: {}}, agencia: {}, conta: {}}
agencia
:
{}
conta
:
{}
nome
:
{0: {}, 1: {}}

Comment: @LucasPletsch Testou o meu exemplo que coloquei na primeira linha da resposta? funcionou?

Comment: O teu funcionou. Mas o teu código não funcionou na minha aplicação. Já consegui resolver,de outra forma.